# "Як наслідок, ..." - калька з російської чи ні?

Tags: калька

Чомусь є відчуття, що оце вставне "як наслідок, ..." - калька з російської, але пошук по словниках не підтвердив, що це так, але хочеться знати напевне.

Comment: Я думаю, ця калька має первісне джерело в європейських мовах: «as a consequence» ([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as-a-consequence-in-consequence), [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-consequence-as-a-consequence)) і т.ін.

Comment: Найперше трапляння «як наслідок» саме як вставного словосполучення (наприклад, щоб не було «це не можна розглядати як наслідок») і саме без залежних слів (щоб не «як наслідок <чогось>»), яке я бачу, — це [1912 року в Грушевського](https://www.m-hrushevsky.name/uk/Publicistics/1907/VyzvolennjaRosii/Nejmovirno.html); але там цитата, і він, можливо, справді цитує якийсь російський указ. А перше, що точно оригінальне — 1923, Юрко Тютюнник: «Момент переходу до наступу був невдало вибраний і, як наслідок, поразка — ціль не була осягнута» («Зимовий похід 1919-20 рр»).

Comment: Зазвичай вживають "в наслідку" тих або інших обставин трапилися ті чи інші речі (події). щоб речення було синтаксично впорядкованим

Comment: [3 результат в моєму гугл пошуку](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/uk/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1/). Чергове нагадування: перш ніж запитувати ви **мусите** докласти всіх зусиль, щоб знайти відповідь на питання самі. **Це найголовніше правило всієї мережі Stack Exchange.** Я б взагалі флагував таке питання як "needs improvement"

Comment: А до чого ваш пошук тут? Питання не про "отже" і "таким чином".